# sh script to build from source Ubuntu

Tags: bash, compilation, cmake

Im trying to automate some dependency installing from an sh script, however, I feel that not all commands are getting through.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Downloads
sudo wget https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/archive/OCE-0.16.1.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf OCE-0.16.1.tar.gz 
cd oce-OCE-0.16.1/
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ../
sudo make
sudo make install/strip
```

Is this valid in a .sh script?

Comment: Compiling as root is a really bad idea. Recommended practice is to build as non-root and only install as root (if required). I speak from experience with a build that somehow managed to run `rm -rf /`

Comment: Try out this site: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @DarkFalcon so you suggest only running the make install commands with sudo? problem is that some systems require make to write files

Comment: Yes. Unless the package is very poorly designed, everything but installation should be able to be done as a non-root user. Yes, cmake, make, and commands they invoke write files, but it should be writing them to the source or build directory, which should be fully writable by the user that untarred the package.